# Getting an error due to using isDate() in a function which in turn is a formula for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I need the following to work on SQL Server 2008 R2

I've got a column to add to a table which needs a formula associated with it for which I'm using a scalar-valued function.

This is the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetSaleDate_fromXML]
(
    @transaction_data    xml
)

RETURNS date

WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    declare @dateXmlValue   varchar(20)
    declare @dateAssembledValueStr  varchar(20)
    declare @dateValue  date

    set @dateXmlValue = '19052014' --this ultimately comes from another column
if @dateXmlValue <> 'Not supplied'
    BEGIN
        set @dateAssembledValueStr = concat(substring(@dateXmlValue, 5, 4), substring(@dateXmlValue, 3, 2), substring(@dateXmlValue, 1, 2))
        if ISDATE(@dateAssembledValueStr) = 1
            BEGIN
                set @dateValue = CONVERT(date, @dateAssembledValueStr, 103)         
            END
    END
    return @dateValue
END
```

I've tested this function with valid and invalid data and it works just fine.

When I try to add this as a forumla for a column, I get the error:

`Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Computed column 'contxxxxxe' in table 'propexxxxxxxxxn' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.`

If I comment the line with the `if ISDATE(@dateAssembledValueStr) = 1`, it works fine.

Research has shown me that using `isDate()` except in a very special case, is non-deterministic. My question is, given my requirement, how do I get around this problem, short of re-creating `IsDate()` myself?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL  Server 2012. I'll edit the post too.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal .... That was a quick edit. Will people searching for questions with Sql-Server tag as opposed to sql-server-2012 tag also be able to see this? I'm asking since even though I'm using sql server 2012, I don't know if the problem is only for this version of Sql Server, which is why I'd used the sql-server tag originally.

Comment: I think I have read somewhere that those tags just work well, that when you add `sql-server-2012` then no need to add general `sql-server`. But cannot find any reference to it now. But now I see other answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions

Comment: Some tags have synonyms - it is the case of `sql-server-2012` and `sql-server`.

Comment: Oh Okay. Well, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ISDATE` with `TRY_CONVERT()` on SQL Server 2012:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

```
set @dateValue = TRY_CONVERT(date, @dateAssembledValueStr, 103)
if @dateValue IS NULL
        --handle invalid date string
```

On SQL Server 2008 R2 you can create your own CLR function.
[See this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/88152/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392500/2224701).

Even if you change the line with `ISDATE` function to

```
if ISDATE(CONVERT(varchar,@dateAssembledValueStr,112)) = 1
```

the error remains the same and the same answer you may find in [this very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9007552/2224701).

Comment: Thanks @VojtěchDohnal. About that earlier comment. Even though, I'm using SQL server 2012, I need something that will work SQL 2008 R2 as well since our production systems are using SQL 2008R2.

Comment: I can't use try catch in a UDF

Comment: @AshwinNair It seems that you need either to write your own ISDATE function in T-SQL or use CLR function.